# kruskal test rows and columns as factors

Tags: r, statistics

I guess I need some R-specific stats help.
Below is my 'experimental design table'.
I would like to test if the distribution of 'scores' is different in genes of typeX vs type_norm in conditions of FamilyF vs all and FamilyG vs all conditions.

Here is my 'experimental design':

```
    FamilyF FamilyF FamilyG FamilyG
gene_type   gene    conditionA  conditionB  conditionC  conditionD
typeX   gene1   1   2   3   4
typeX   gene2   0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
typeX   gene3   -1  -2  -3  -4
norm    gene4   10  20  30  40
norm    gene5   1   2   3   4
norm    gene6   0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
```

I have don't previous analysis before just testing for differences in distributions among the genes in the different conditions, using the kruskal test and something like.

rearrange the data to this:

```
gene    gene1   gene2   gene3   gene4   gene5   gene6   Family
conditionA  1   0.1 -1  10  1   0.1 F
conditionB  2   0.2 -2  20  2   0.2 F
conditionC  3   0.3 -3  30  3   0.3 G
conditionD  4   0.4 -4  40  4   0.4 G
```

Then I made a loop for columns gene1-gene6, and the different metadata columns for the conditions, and performed kruskal test, as below.

```
kt<-kruskal.test(df.plsMD[,"gene1"]~df.plsMD[,"Family"])
```

But I am not sure how to perform something similar with rows AND columns as factors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can't do that in one analysis. You wil have to subset your dataframe for the different genes like this:

```
df.gene1 <- subset(df, gene = "gene1")
df.gene2 <- subset(df, gene = "gene2")
....
```

After that, you can use a Kruskal test:

```
kruskal.test(conditionA ~ gene_type, data = df.gene1)
```

If this gives a significant result, you can check where the differences occur with:

```
df.gene1$Ranks.gene_type <- rank(sophdata$conditionA)
by(df.gene1$Ranks.gene_type, df.gene1$gene_type, mean)
kruskalmc(conditionA ~ gene_type, data = df.gene1)
```